# SQL import using temporary table has no result (nor error)

Tags: mysql, sql, import, phpmyadmin

I want to import some values (1 column) using only SQL. The query I wrote looks like it should work, but when I enter it in phpMyAdmin, it just resets the SQL form (I had to write it again the first time) and no inserts are performed. Also, there are no error messages.

The target table (`contact`) has the same structure as the temporary one with some extra fields.

```
create temporary table import(
id int,
postalcode varchar(255)
);

insert into import values
(1,'city1'),
(2,'city2'),
...
;

insert into contact(city) (
    select postalcode from import 
    inner join contact on contact.id=import.id
)
where contact.id=import.id
```

I added the `inner join` clause because the query couldn’t find the `contact.id` column in the `where` clause. Is this the right approach for this case?

Comment: What is the structure of your contact table? Are you trying to update/insert/upsert existing contacts with import?

Comment: Also try this in sqlfiddle and share the link, it will be easier to help you that way.

Comment: Are you running all of the above queries in ONE go? It may not work then. PHP by default doesn't allow multiple queries in one execution (separated by semi-colons). Perhaps this is the reason.

Comment: WHICH of the above queries are you running, that is not producing the results?

Comment: It is absurd to use the WHERE clause AND the inner join at the same tie in this way. Remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: the WHERE clause is part of the INSERT and the INNER JOIN is part of the SELECT subquery. i edited to correct my code accordingly by adding brackets.

Comment: and yes im running them at once, im not aware padmin explicitly doesnt allow this. PHP does contain a `mysqli_multi_query()`. and if i replace the 3rd statement, the actual insert with a select * from import, it does execute all of them and shows a correct results set. (it does give out warnings/errors as well: **unknown table type**/**unknown table comment**).

Comment: sqlfiddle isnt of much help here, since it doesnt support TEMPORARY TABLE statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution turned out to be:

```
insert into contact (id,city)(select * from import)
on duplicate key update city=values(city);
```

[View on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0df87/1/0).

This is awesome and will save so much time on writing back-end scripts for import.